# Last function not hiding divs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a the functions below that do the following:

1. hides div
2. show divs when option selected is clicked
3. hides div when button is clicked.

The very last function is not working for some reason. The divs will not hide again.

```
$(function() {
  $("#event").hide();
  $("#events").hide();
  $("#myselect select").change(function() {
    var $selected = $('#myselect select option:selected');
    if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
     $('<li />', {
        'data-value': $selected.val(),
        text: $selected.text()
      }).appendTo('#events');
      $selected.addClass('added')
    }
    $("#event").show();
    $("#events").show();
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#promo").hide();
  $("#promos").hide();
  $("#myselect2 select").change(function() {
    var $selected = $('#myselect2 select option:selected');
    if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
      $('<li />', {
        'data-value': $selected.val(),
        text: $selected.text()
      }).appendTo('#promos');
      $selected.addClass('added')
    }
    $("#promo").show();
    $("#promos").show();
  });
});

$(function() {
$('#grab1').click(function) {
$('#promo').hide();
$('#promos').hide();
});
});
```

Comment: please fiddle your query..thanks

Comment: sure, give me few moments please

Comment: You can wrap all the codes within one `$(function() {})` block.also please remove the codeigniter tag.

Comment: @TusharGupta here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qrqapz38/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last function, try something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#grab1').click(function() {
    $('#promo').hide();
    $('#promos').hide();
  })
});
```

Comment: here is the fiddle jsfiddle.net/qrqapz38/1

Comment: I was missing a closing ) on the 5th line, above. I edited. Not sure if it solves the problem, but it might.

Comment: @Pinoniq it's different in that the OPs .click function definition was not included in the .click arguments, unless there is some funky syntax allowed that I'm not aware of (I'm never sure with JS).

Comment: Good job @brybott that was exactly it. It was the semicolon on the 2nd bracket to last. Marked as right answer. Not sure why, though brackets were supposed to have semicolon at end.

Comment: Somehow here on my end they are exactly the same :p

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
     $("#event").hide();
      $("#events").hide();
      $("#promo").hide();
      $("#promos").hide();

      $("#myselect select").change(function() {
        var $selected = $('#myselect select option:selected');
        if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
         $('<li />', {
            'data-value': $selected.val(),
            text: $selected.text()
          }).appendTo('#events');
          $selected.addClass('added')
        }
        $("#event").show();
        $("#events").show();
      });

      $("#myselect2 select").change(function() {
        var $selected = $('#myselect2 select option:selected');
        if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
          $('<li />', {
            'data-value': $selected.val(),
            text: $selected.text()
          }).appendTo('#promos');
          $selected.addClass('added')
        }
        $("#promo").show();
        $("#promos").show();
      });

    $("#grab1").click(function(){
        $("#event").hide();
        $("#events").hide();
    });

     $("#grab2").click(function(){
        $("#promos").hide();
        $("#promo").hide();
    });
});
```